# How can a non-crypto-expert implement crypto libraries in a programming language?

Tags: implementation, dsa

I'm a regular developer and thus not a crypto expert. I'd like to use ECDSA as a library in a programming language, [Idris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idris_(programming_language)), which still doesn't have one. I could, obviously, try and port a particular implementation of my choice, run some tests, and call it a day. But that sounds unprincipled for something that needs strong security.

Is there any standard procedure or best practices to guide a normal developer to implement such a thing properly, without falling on the "don't roll your own crypto" trap?

Comment: ECDSA signature generation is tricky, as if you get the random number generation wrong (and a small bias is enough), you can leak the private key.  You might want to consider something like EdDSA (which avoids that particular rake-in-the-grass) instead

Comment: @poncho specifically I'd like to perform Ethereum/Bitcoin transaction signing on Idris. I guess there isn't much I can do other than using FFI, then? (It would be good to avoid it because it is tricky to build an FFI for every compile target.) (EDIT: I read those use ECDSA, but I believe there is no RNG involved - I'm confused now.)

Comment: There are ways of implementing ECDSA without an rng ("determanistic ECDSA"), however I would agree with Ella's answer: if you don't know what you're doing, use a library written by someone who does.

Comment: @poncho which kinda sucks as it means I can't use a set of existing languages. I suspected there would be some kind of standard process to port those libs around. Why aren't crypto libraries programmed in a language that can easily run inside other languages?

Comment: @MaiaVictor You could probably use something like libsodium with Idris's C FFI. Unless you're trying to do something like have, say, the entire thing implemented or represented in a lambda calculus (based on your optimal lambda calculus evaluation work I've seen).

Comment: It is interesting though: You'd think there'd be at least a bit more overlap between the crypto community and the formal methods/dependently typed programming language community than there seems to be.

Comment: @MaiaVictor What is "a language that can easily run inside other languages?"  I don't think I've ever seen one of those.  Javascript, Lua, Python, LISP... none of those are easy, and those are the easy ones that I know of compared to others like C, C#, or Java.  I suppose you could implement it in brainf---k.  That's easy to interpret.

Comment: @CortAmmon that is an old thought I have and something I do not comprehend. Why don't most languages target a common, small, expressive core? Haskell does that and is faster than most that don't, so performance isn't an argument. If everyone agreed with a common core, programming languages would be just syntactical sugar, and sharing code between them would be trivial...

Comment: @DavidYoung (ref above). Idris's C FFI would not work on the JS backend. Do you have an opinion on the matter?

Comment: @MaiaVictor In my experience, most compilers do go to a smaller intermediate representation (LLVM bitcode is probably the closest to what you're describing and somewhat widespread. The clang C and C++ compiler compiles to it and GHC, eventually, generates that by default, I believe). As far as using Idris's JS FFI here goes, it looks like there is a JavaScript version of [libsodium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsodium). Speaking of LLVM, it looks like it was generated using [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten), which converts LLVM bitcode to JavaScript.

Comment: @MaiaVictor "If everyone agreed with a common core .. sharing code would be trivial."  My experience is that most of computing consists of things where "if everyone agreed, life woudl be amazing," but actually getting people to agree turns out to be way more difficult than we think.  Not for lack of trying though.  I can count dozens of attempts to come up with a "common core" which went by the wayside when we found out how uncommon those are.  I used 3 of them today!

Comment: @CortAmmon 3 of them?

Comment: @MaiaVictor Yeah, Corba, HLA, and Java.  Each was touted as being a common core within its particular domain, and each one had to admit that that was a loftier goal than they thought.

Comment: @DavidYoung maybe you're right... I think my problem with LLVM, WASM and the like is that they completely destroy the logical structure of the program, which has many consequences... for one, you need to manually specify the FFI... with CoC & similar, that could be automated, I guess?

Comment: @CortAmmon any of those coming from the "functional" PoV (type-theory terms) rather than a assembly-like virtual machine? (I think you're right but I'm curious if any serious company attempted that - if so, why it didn't work, if not, why?)

Comment: @MaiaVictor All were "high level" approaches in their own domain, and Corba could be thought of in type theory terms, though it doesn't really fit into the two bins you gave me.  Of course, if by "common core" you mean "functional programming," then the discussion is different.  In the case of functional programming, you have to account for the *massive* inertia of the majority of programmers not being convinced this "common core" is a core at all.  It takes a lot of education to re-train someone to think functionally.

Comment: @CortAmmon I think one of the points is that a sufficiently expressive functional core could be converted to native, imperative langs such as LLVM, whereas the opposite isn't true... so that most programmers wouldn't need to be convinced about anything FP-related, it'd be just an internal, common format compilers etc. would use to pass code around. (I think.)

Comment: @MaiaVictor In order for very different languages to interact, you must destroy logical structure. Ultimately, the only thing that languages necessarily have in common are the instructions that end up being executed by the machine. Imagine trying to interface INTERCAL with Python (or INTERCAL with anything, frankly) at a high level, preserving high level structures. Or CUDA with Forth. Whether it's represented in lambda calculus or assembly, there will be enough of an impedance mismatch that you will need a manual FFI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best option is to avoid doing so as much as possible. Ideally, your language of choice will offer a [wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library) around a battle tested library such as [libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/) (or maybe [bearssl](https://bearssl.org/) one day).

Additionally, in a perfect world, the interface that the library/wrapper provides should be designed to make it [difficult if not impossible](https://www.lvh.io/posts/nonce-misuse-resistance-101.html) for you as the developer to shoot yourself in the foot. For example, if generation of the nonce for some kind of [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29)-like mode is left up to you and not handled by the libraries you're using, you probably want to use a different library.